# Why individual count is different than overall count in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

how it is possible to get different record count for individual column than the overall count.please find below query/results.

```
hive> select count(*) from table1 group by hif_cycle_date;

9920279
14664577

hive> select count(*) as record from table1;

11020279
```

sum of 9920279 + 14664577 should be equal to overall but .. different

Comment: You probably have duplicates in the 'hif_cycle_date' variable. When you apply the group by, only unique occurences of 'hif_cycle_date' will be counted.

Comment: but group by giving more count than the overall count .....